# Provisioning Profile and NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore Problems

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile, code-signing-entitlements, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

The app I'm currently working on was originally developed by someone else on another mac and has several provisioning profiles linked to it. I made a new provisioning profile about a month ago to test on the same device the original developer tested on and everything was working fine. Since the past couple of days I have received this error when running the app on a device:

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error: com.companyname.appname has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement
```

I researched this error and came to the conclusion that my entitlements were wrong in some way. I then discovered they were turned off which is something I did to get the new provisioning profile to work on the device. I turned the entitlements on again and got this familiar error:

```
The executable was signed with invalid entitlements ... (0xE8008016).
```

I've tried a lot of suggestions from various sources on the internet to solve this problem but none of them seemed to work, which is why I originally turned the entitlements off (the one suggestion that worked).

The provisioning profile I created is listed as valid under the devices' provisioning profiles tab. There are 4 other provisioning profiles which are only listed in the libraries' provisioning profiles tab.

Can an app be uploaded to the store without an entitlements file?

Can the final distribution of the app and upload of the binary be conducted and the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error: won't be present?

Can anyone give me a fairly comprehensive step by step guide to completely removing the link between the old provisioning profile and the current entitlements or a way of changing the entitlements file to work with the current provisioning profile?

I am aware this sort of error is pretty hard to diagnose and solve but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the source of my problem to be that the provisioning profile I was trying to sign the app to had a wildcard* appID so therefore would not match. A pretty stupid error but one possibly other people may encounter.